# Firefox Extension Development: How to correctly specify the anchor element for a notification popup?

Tags: popup, firefox-addon, notifications, anchor

being new to JavaScript and Firefox extension development, I'm trying to set the anchor element for a [popup notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/PopupNotifications.jsm), but it doesn't seem to work, it's being either ignored, or the notification doesn't show up at all.

Neither just giving the label as a plain string nor something like document.getElementById("xyz") or alike worked, and since I'm new to the whole matter I don't even know what exactly to look for on google, at least I couldn't find anything helpful.

Anybody can help a newbie? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to call it?

Answer (score 1):

The anchorID is (correctly) described in the linked document as a string giving the id of an element in the document that should serve as the anchor of the notification.

Note that the element should be an image child of the `notification-popup-box` element, and CSS will be needed to ensure that the icon is visible when the notification is created.

```
#notification-popup-box[anchorid="my-notification-icon"] > #my-notification-icon {
  display: -moz-box;
}
```